# When I am developing Android application ,I want to modify the background of a item after I set a adapter for this ListView

Tags: android, listview, background

When I am developing Android application ,I want to modify the background of a item in ListView after I set a adapter for this ListView,how to do it ?? thank  you

Comment: Your question doesn't convey anything...What you really want to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I unterstood your question correctly then maybe you can try the following example to change the background of the listitems...
You should override the adapter's
    `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`
method this way:
...
`convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mybackground));`
...